# Defining Parameters and Logical Operators (<=, =, >=) by combobox Reportviewer

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, reportviewer

I have a form where I define the search conditions to generate one report! It's all fine with the textboxes, it works perfectly. For this I coded:

```
 if (fprmc.comboBox2.Text == "")
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.ClienteTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente, fprmc.textBox2.Text, fprmc.textBox1.Text, fprmc.textBox3.Text, fprmc.textBox4.Text);
            this.ClienteTableAdapter.Fill2(this.DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente, fprmc.textBox2.Text, fprmc.textBox1.Text, fprmc.textBox3.Text, fprmc.textBox4.Text);
            this.ClienteTableAdapter.Fill3(this.DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente, fprmc.textBox2.Text, fprmc.textBox1.Text, fprmc.textBox3.Text, fprmc.textBox4.Text);
            this.ClienteTableAdapter.Fill4(this.DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente, fprmc.textBox2.Text, fprmc.textBox1.Text, fprmc.textBox3.Text, fprmc.textBox4.Text);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

This code above works like the way I want.
BUT, you can see that I have a combobox, and it is my problem.
I need to define, when a certain value is selected, the order and the sort of the Report. If I choose "Cliente" it should be likt this:

```
else if (fprmc.comboBox2.Text == "Cliente")
        {
            this.ClienteTableAdapter.FillByCliente(this.DataSetReportsCliente.Cliente, fprmc.textBox2.Text, fprmc.textBox1.Text, fprmc.textBox3.Text, fprmc.textBox4.Text);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

and then, return all the Report with an alphabetical sort by "Cliente". But it don't happen.

I wrote the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT        IDCliente, NumeroCliente, Nome, NIF, Email, Endereco1, Endereco2, CodigoPostal, Pais 
FROM            Cliente 
WHERE        (NumeroCliente LIKE '%' + @NumeroC + '%') AND (Nome LIKE '%' + @NomeC + '%') AND (NIF LIKE '%' + @Nif + '%') AND (Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%')
 ORDER BY Nome
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Best regards guys!

Comment: what doesn't happen? It returns nothing? or not sorted? maybe the data  is returned correctly, but it is sorted differently in your viewer/

Comment: It returns all the records without filters, not sorted :\